# I need to run a set of(10) oracle select queries hourly and the each result should be copied into same excel in different tabs

Tags: database, excel, oracle

Suppose these 2 queries needs to be run every hour:

```
select count(*) from v$session;
```

Second query:

```
select * from gv$resource_limit where resource_name in ('processes','sessions');
```

So, The result needs to be copied in different tabs of excel sheet

and if possible same sheet should be carried out for 24 hours.

How can I execute it?

Comment: Don't think this is possible in SQL. You will Need to write a script in something like GO or PYTHON

Comment: Please assist if any other way possible

Comment: add details and format